# How to use TCMalloc by it's header but not instead of malloc, new

Tags: c++, malloc, tcmalloc

I'm adding TCMalloc to my project. My method is linking .a to my project, so all of malloc, new, free... will be replaced by implement of TCMalloc. But some of malloc in my project can't be replaced because of some reason. So now, I want to use tc_malloc in the header file but not replace all malloc. How can I do it?

I know that malloc is a weak symbol so if link the library to my project will replace it. Do you have some method to only use tc_malloc?

Comment: _But some of malloc in my project can't be replaced because of some reason_ What reason?

Comment: Because I'm using a cluster, which host cores and slave cores' memory is based segment management. So origin malloc is be changed but I can't to change it. So when the cluster init, it will call that malloc, which tcmalloc is wrong, and in my codes, I want to call tcmalloc. Just for this :-(

Comment: I consider that tc_malloc gives me a header which have interface of tc_malloc, so I want to ask for only calling tc_malloc but not replace all malloc.

Comment: I very much doubt that a mixed approach would work, since both allocators assume that they can do as they please.

Comment: You are right. I succeed avoiding the override. But it looks not working by tcmalloc. Maybe I should write a allocator by myself. Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the overrides are in the [`libc_override.h`](https://github.com/google/tcmalloc/blob/master/tcmalloc/libc_override.h) file, which is compiled by default.
However, there is a [second target](https://github.com/google/tcmalloc/blob/master/tcmalloc/BUILD#L113-L133) which does not include this file.

`bazel build //tcmalloc:tcmalloc_internal_methods_only` should get you a TCMalloc library without the override.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your anwser. I succeed getting a TCMalloc lib without the override.